# Comment traduire « line of fire (hazards, accidents, safety) » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, travail

> To safety professionals, *line of fire hazards* occur when a worker is
> in the danger zone if a release of energy would cause the worker to be
> hit, struck, pinched, impaled, crushed, caught between objects.
> Injuries from *line of fire accidents* range from minor, such as a
> pinched finger, all the way to a fatality. ([jsabuilder](https://www.jsabuilder.com/resources/line-of-fire-safety.php))
>
> Don’t Ignore *Line of Fire Safety*: Here’s What You Need to Know
> ([premiersafetypartners](https://premiersafetypartners.com/line-of-fire-safety/))

Il s'agit d'une forme d'analogie avec la *ligne de tir* (du danger etc. pour ainsi dire) dans le domaine de la sécurité au travail. Comment s'y prend-on pour traduire ce nom qui vient qualifier « hazards (risques, dangers) », « accidents » ou « safety (le sujet de la sécurité) », voire simplement l'idée du travailleur qui est dans cette « ligne de tir » ?

Comment: Il s'agit bien à mon avis d'une "ligne de tir" litérale, l'énergie (ou projectile...) partant directement dans la direction du travailleur, donc pour ma part j'utiliserais directement "ligne de tir".

Comment: @Frank La ligne de tir... du risque, de l'accident, de la sécurité ?? Je ne crois pas.

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai. L'article anglais ci-dessus _définit_ "line of fire hazards". Hmmm... _Dangers à projections linéaires_? _Dangers à projections directes_? _Dangers à projections radiales_?

Comment: L'expression "être en première ligne" pourra s'appliquer  pour indiquer que le travailleur est dans la zone la plus périlleuse, comparativement à ses collègues plus en sécurité..

Comment: @Graffito Oui, mais c'est légèrement imprécis dépendamment du contexte. Prend un câble que tu essayes de couper avec une lame et où tu appliques une pression dans la direction de ton corps vs. dans la direction opposée. Tu es au même endroit dans les deux cas, mais dans un seul tu es dans la _line of fire_.

Answer (score 4):

Le seul terme générique que je vois est ***zone de danger*** (ou ***zone dangereuse***) signalée par un triangle jaune contenant un pictogramme accompagné d'une description du danger:

[image]

[image]

On trouve dans une jurisprudence l'expression *ligne de mire du danger* :

> La société [Y] soutient que M. [H], employé depuis 30 ans en qualité de mécanicien, a bénéficié de formations régulières, dont une en 2017 aux fonctions de pontier-élingueur, et de causeries sur la sécurité, dont une consacrée à l'importance de ne pas rester dans la ligne de mire du danger.

Source: [Dalloz](https://www.dalloz.fr/documentation/Document?id=CA_AMIENS_2023-05-04_2105809#texte-integral)

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t J'en reviens toujours à l'idée d'une explosion avec un projectile qui part en ligne droite et atteint la victime. En anglais, une expression un peu similaire, c'est _ligne of sight_ (qui ne s'applique pas ici), mais qui est la même idée de ligne droite.

Comment: En fait, je suggérerais quelque chose comme "_dangers à projections radiales directes_". Un peu périphrastique, mais bon, ça évite les histoires de _tir_.

Comment: J'ai trouvé *ligne de mire du danger* dans une [jurisprudence](https://www.dalloz.fr/documentation/Document?id=CA_AMIENS_2023-05-04_2105809#texte-integral) et dans un livre (Meurtres sans frontières, Terry Gould).

Comment: Oui, j'avais pensé à _ligne de mire_ aussi, mais comme l'OP avait refusé _ligne de tir_, je me suis dit que _mire_ évoquait une visée qui plairait encore moins à l'OP :-)

Comment: Je me suis rabattu sur _projections_ pour éviter toute histoire de _tir_ ou d'intentionalité de la part du danger lui-même, et puis j'ai ajouté _radial_ et _direct_ pour approximer _ligne_.

Comment: @Frank *Ligne de mire* est il me semble plus propice à des utilisations au sens figuré.

Comment: Et _projection_ est plus général - il n'y a pas forcément de projectile, peut-être un écrasement dû à une décharge d'énergie malencontreuse. L'énergie est _projetée_ dans la direction de la victime.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui - mais ce qui me dérange, c'est ces histoires de _tir_, _visée_...? On peut sans doute garder et voir le danger comme "tirant" sur la victime, mais je préfère pour ma part _projection_, un peu comme _éclaboussure_, et parce qu'il n'est pas clair s'il y a toujours un "projectile".

Comment: @Frank Pourquoi pas, *dans la zone de projection du danger* ou aussi *dans l'axe de projection du danger*. Tu peux le proposer.

Comment: @jlliagre "Zone de projection" - très bien. Je fais une réponse officielle autour de _projection_ alors?

Comment: @Frank C'est haut pour toi !

Comment: @jlliagre Alors là je suis perdu :-) "haut"? "Haut pour qq'un" - c'est une expression?

Comment: @Frank C'est un joke. Traduit la phrase en anglais :-)

Comment: @jlliagre Je t'ai upvoté :-)

Answer (score 1):

Je proposerais l'utilisation du mot *projection*, avec éventuellement des additifs, tels que *axial* (merci @jiliagre!) ou *radial*, ou *direct* pour maintenir l'idée de *ligne directe* entre le danger et la victime.

Les expressions *lignes de tir*, *ligne de mire* ne me paraissent pas entièrement souhaitables, car elles évoquent une intentionalité qui ne se trouve pas dans le danger en question (le danger ne "tire" pas intentionnellement). Et aussi, suivant la description anglaise, il n'y a pas forcément de projectile impliqué, alors que ces termes empruntés à l'artillerie suggèrent fortement un projectile. Il se peut que ce soit une énergie qui se déplace en ligne directe pour causer le mouvement d'un objet lourd sur cette ligne, où se trouve également la victime qui sera écrasée. *Projection* me paraît donc plus général, et fait pendant à "release of energy".

J'utiliserais donc une expression comme:

> danger à projection linéaire/radiale/directe/axiale
>
> zone de projection du danger (merci @jiliagre!)
>
> axe de projection du danger (merci @jiliagre!)

Comment: Ouais, _axe_ +1.

Answer (score 1):

Une solution possible, [***trajectoire***](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trajectoire) :

“[STAY OUT OF THE PIG’S LINE OF FIRE](https://www.cer-rec.gc.ca/en/safety-environment/industry-performance/information-safety-advisories/safety-advisory/2007/archive/neb-sa-2007-01-pipeline-pigging-operations-open-injury.pdf)” / « [NE VOUS PLACEZ PAS DANS LA TRAJECTOIRE DU RACLEUR](https://www.cer-rec.gc.ca/fr/securite-environnement/rendement-lindustrie/avis-securite-dinformation/avis-securite/2007/archive/one-sa-2007-01-activites-raclage-pipelines-risque-blessure.pdf) »

Comment formuler « line of fire hazards occur when a worker is in the danger zone », « Injuries from line of fire accidents range from... » et « Don’t Ignore Line of Fire Safety » avec les termes trouvés ?